# Using Regex with Kotlin

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

According to http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html, my regex

```
\\uline\{[a-zA-Z\d]+\}|\\text(super|sub)script\{[0-9]+.[0-9]+\}
```

should work fine to detect e.g.
1) \textsuperscript{1.1}
and
2) \uline{name}

Furthermore, replaceFirst works as expected:
12345\textsuperscript{1.1}6789 goes to 123456789

I doubled backslashes and added the regex to my Kotlin code (in IntelliJ Idea):

```
var stylingRegex = "\\\\uline\\{[a-zA-Z\\d]+\\}|\\\\text(super|sub)script    \\{[0-9]+.[0-9]+\\}"
var testString = "12345\\uline{james}678"
testString = testString.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(stylingRegex), "")
println("testString: " + testString)
```

However, what's printed is the initialized string without any modification.

Comment: You should not quote the regex, remove `Pattern.quote()`, use `testString = testString.replaceFirst(stylingRegex.toRegex(), "")`

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/ZVIA41689) showing that Wiktor's suggestion fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not `quote` the regex pattern and you should make sure you pass a regex to the `replaceFirst`:

```
testString = testString.replaceFirst(stylingRegex.toRegex(), "")
```

See the [online Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/XXO60993):

```
var stylingRegex = """\\uline\{[a-zA-Z\d]+\}|\\text(super|sub)script\{[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\}"""
var testString = "12345\\uline{james}678"
testString = testString.replaceFirst(stylingRegex.toRegex(), "")
println("testString: " + testString)
// => testString: 12345678
```

Note that you do not need to use excessive backslashes when using raw string literals (defined with `"""...""""`), inside them, the `\` symbol denotes a literal backslash that is used to create regex escapes.

Also, to match float numbers only, you need to escape the dot in the `[0-9]+.[0-9]+` part of your pattern. To match both integer and float, use `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?`.